# basic, about specifier

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
  double n1,n2;
  float n3;
  printf("input 2 flt:");
  scanf("%lf %lf",&n1,&n2);
  n3 = n1 * n2;
  printf("n1 * n2 = %.2lf",n3);
}
```

when I set n1,n2 to be float, n3 cannot be correctly calculated ,why?

code originally from [a online tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/product-numbers), modified to test the function of %lf.

Comment: What is your input, output you are getting and expected output?

Comment: Are you still reading them as %lf or changing to %f?

Comment: While it isn't wrong, note that you don't need the `l` length modifier with `%f` to print `double`s with `printf()`.

Comment: @DavidBowling note that OP is using `lf` to print a `float`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala-- true, but the `l` has no effect on the `f` conversion specifier here. (A `float` argument is converted to a `double` in variadic function calls anyway, but now we are getting out of the scope of the question ;))

Comment: You must use %f.
Also read this:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/215065/can-anyone-explain-representation-of-float-in-memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to use the correct `scanf()` specifier.

If you use `float` then `"%f"`, and `"%lf"` if you use `double`.

For `float`, you would do it like this

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float n1, n2;
    float n3;

    printf("input 2 flt:");
    if (scanf("%f%f", &n1, &n2) == 2) {
        n3 = n1 * n2;
        printf("n1 * n2 = %.2f",n3);
    }
}
```

And for `double`

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double n1, n2;
    double n3;

    printf("input 2 flt:");
    if (scanf("%lf%lf", &n1, &n2) == 2) {
        n3 = n1 * n2;
        printf("n1 * n2 = %.2f",n3);
    }
}
```

Note that I checked that `scanf()` returned `2` before using the values of  `n1` and `n2`, that's because if you don't check the program might invoke undefined behavior due to `n1` and/or `n2` not being initialized.

Your `printf()` specifier is also wrong, for both `float` and `double` **you can use** `"%f"`, read the documentation.

Comment: if gcc less important as gcc analyse the format string and makes the necessary casts

Comment: Note that [an `l` length modifer has no effect on a following `f` conversion specifier in `printf()` format strings](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p7), so `%lf` will work equally well for `float` or `double`.

Comment: @mch `%Lf` is the specifier for `long double`

Answer (score 1):

You must use `%f`.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
int main(){
float n1,n2;
float n3;
printf("input 2 flt:");
scanf("%f %f",&n1,&n2);
n3 = n1 * n2;
printf("n1 * n2 = %.2f",n3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from other answers，I learnt the `%f %lf` things are called format specifiers.

`f lf` are for different data-types. `f` is for float  `lf` for double

this site listed all [spes](http://codeforwin.in/2015/05/list-of-all-format-specifiers-in-c-programming.html).

---

and I checked c11 standard, found the `l` before `f` is called a length modifier.